# Вывод лесенкой с for

Tags: c

У меня есть кусок кода, к примеру, пишу номер 5 и мне выводится пирамида с номером 5

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Нужно, чтобы выглядело так

```
****1
***22
**333
*4444
55555
```

Кусок моего кода

```
for (i = 0; numero > i; i++) {
    for (k = i; k >= 0; k--) {
        printf("*");
    }
    printf("n");
}

system("PAUSE");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте вы тоже будете думать, хорошо?

В `i`-ой строке нам надо выдать (1) сколько звёздочек? (2) сколько цифр? (3) каких именно цифр?

Как только вы ответите себе на эти вопросы, код станет самоочевиден.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)

{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        if ( j < (N - (i + 1)) )
           printf("*");
        else
           printf(i+1);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Ыыыыы. И чему автор вопроса научится, получив готовый код? Вы за него всю жизнь программировать будете?

Comment: Он никогда не будет программировать, если он обращается за помощью при возникновении таких задач. А на деле может быть поможет школьнику притащить еще одну хорошую оценку и получить конфетку от мамы. Да и просто делать нечего

Comment: "Не стоит жалеть двоечников -- один из них скорее всего станет вашим начальником" (c)